# Two SELECT actions in a query with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to perform a search with a date range - from the result, display only the rows which has a particular value (listed in a different column). Which means two SELECT actions involved in a query. I am not getting through this query correctly.

My query is here

```
$sql="SELECT (SELECT * FROM `student_db` 
          WHERE `stu_registered_date` 
          BETWEEN '2015-01-07' AND '2015-01-17') 
      WHERE `stu_trainer_id` LIKE 'Trainer-1'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need 2 queries rather one query with 2 conditions

```
      SELECT * FROM `student_db` 
      WHERE `stu_registered_date` 
      BETWEEN '2015-01-07' AND '2015-01-17'
      and `stu_trainer_id` = 'Trainer-1'
```

Comment: Thank you! But MSQL says: `#1054 - Champ 'stu_trainer_id = Trainer-1' inconnu dans order clause `

Comment: Hmm looks like the column is not available into the table. Please provide the table structure and in which table `stu_trainer_id` belongs ? show the table definition for that table too.

Comment: i don see where the problem is.. for the first time when i tried your suggestion, the above error msg was thrown. I double checked my table details, everything was perfect! After when there is no other go, i dropped the table and redone it! Hurrey!! its working perfectly now! Thank you very much!